# NullPointer when checking if file exists ( file.exists )

Tags: android, file

My application contains a listview. Each listitem contains out of a imageview and a textview.
For showing the image i need check if the image exists in de application data folder.

My code works in the most situations, but there is 1 situation where the application crashes every time i try.

I use the following code to check if the image exists:

```
File file = new File(imgHelper.getSaveImageDirectoryThumb1(imageUrl));
if(file.exists()){  
      //show image
}
```

Sometimes i get the following error, else the get view gets closed without giving a error..
Is there anyone who have a clue to make sure the application won't crash or close the view?

Comment: In which line you get exception?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

A try catch should catch any errors you are getting

```
try{
    File file = new File(imgHelper.getSaveImageDirectoryThumb1(imageUrl));
    if(file){
         //the file is here
    }else{
         //display error
    }
catch(Exception e){
     //Error message
}
```

Comment: print the exception out to logcat and you'll see what the error is

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you did not give more code or the exact error message, I suppose there is something wrong with the

```
imgHelper.getSaveImageDirectoryThumb1(imageUrl)
```

This might return NULL. Apart from checking if `file!=null` you should also have a look at the code mentioned above.

Comment: Still crashes when checking if null.. But thanx for help, try and catch solved it already

Comment: Yes, this particular issue might be solved, but not the problem! Try - catch is in this case extremely dirty (and also has a generic Exception handler!), so I would **not** recommend using this, but look for the reason what caused the problem.

Comment: When i log the error in the catch i get the following Nullpointer:01-13 14:03:32.355: ERROR/error(31931): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Why can't i use this as a solution because when the nullpointer is catched, the image will be replaced with a Img not available image..

Comment: Because what Stevanicus did is not "good programming" style.
Either check with `if (file!=null)` if `file` is not null instead of using the try-catch statement above, or find out **why** the value is null.

Comment: @Force http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html